# I'm trying to write a script to search a folder full of images and compare them to one specific image and find the image that is the most similar

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

This is what I have so far: the output of the script doesn't even print the difference values yet.

```
import os
import sys
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
import cv2

im1 =  cv2.imread("7.jpeg");
dir= '/Users/Desktop/images'
//I'm trying to search the specified directory and compare each image 
in the "images" folder to im1. Then compute the difference between the 
two images for each image in the folder. Lastly I want the program to 
output the name of the image that has the smallest difference with im1.

def get_nb_files(dir):
  for r in dir:
      grayA = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      grayB = cv2.cvtColor(r, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
      (score, diff) = compare_ssim(im1, r, full=True)
      print("SSIM: {}".format(score))
```

Comment: Okay, and what is your question? In case that's the issue, Python uses `#` for comments, not `//` as C does. ;) Now, if searching files is the issue, do a websearch for that and if you have problems with the solutions you find, as specific questions here. Proceed similarly with other steps.

Comment: `for r in dir:` you'll need to read the image `r`.